When the Chrome browser opens I don't see the website I'm testing
I don't know what else I can do more. I am learning Selenium with Python, im in the following situation which I cannot solve, let's see if someone can help me.
By developing a simple test, I am able to execute it completely and correctly. But I can't see the website where the test is being done, pops up in the browser is showed always, I attached an image where it asks me to "Choose your search engine", I have verified that the URL loads correctly. I only can see the web testing if i remove that notification manually. IS THERE ANY POSSIBILITY TO SKIP THAT? I have tried adding some options to the webdriver in the code but I can't find the solution. Someone help me please.
I attach a screenshot of what I get and my code.
Thank you very much in advance.
image where it asks me to "Choose your search engine"
my code
I have tried adding some options to the webdriver in the code but I can't find the solution.

it is pretty simple you just need to add a new option in Chrome options as follows
options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-search-engine-choice-screen")

It will make sure chrome will not ask to select search engine

its working!!!!. thanks a lot!!!!

Perfect then upvote answer so that in the future someone can find it quickly
